# Requested object is not found and cannot be processed. When entering detail view of XAF NonPersistant object

Tags: xaf

My Non Persistant business object is something like this

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
[DomainComponent]
[DefaultClassOptions]
public class AcmeResult : NonPersistentObjectBase{

   [Key] public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

At runtime, when I open the listview and double click to enter detail view I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong namespace for the key attribute.
The following works.

```
[DevExpress.ExpressApp.Data.Key] public int Id { get; set; }
```